# Strange behavior observed when iterating over list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I has a small question,
Let me share a small snippet of code

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in num:
    print(i)
    num[2] = 5
```

here the output is

```
1
2
5
4
```

the iterator's value got updated to 5 instead of 3 in the 3rd iteration, now if I do this

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in num:
    print(i)
    num = [5 if j == 3 else j for j in num]
```

the output is

```
1
2
3
4
```

the iterator stayed the same this the 3rd iteration
Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?
(I observed this in Python 3.8 or 2.7)

Comment: The general idea is to *not* update the collection you are iterating over in a loop. btw there are no iterators in your code samples.

Comment: The `for` loop gets an *iterator* once of `num` at the beginning of the loop, which then looks at each value in the list one by one. `num = ...` replaces the variable `num` with a different list, but that's of no interest to the `for` loop, because it doesn't look at `num` again after it has already gotten its iterator.

Comment: Your first example mutates the list; your second example creates a new list and assigns it to `num` while you continue to iterate over the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the for loop, it takes the id of the provided object and iterates over it.

In the first code snippet, you are changing an element of the original object, so when the iterator reaches the second element it takes the updated value.

However, in the second case you are creating a new object with different values, but the object that you provided to the loop stays the same.

A way of checking this behaviour is to get the id of the variable before and after the modifications, and see how it does not change in the first case but it changes in the second case:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
original_id = id(my_list)

# Check if the object identification changes after modifying one element
my_list[2] = 4
new_id = id(my_list)
if original_id == new_id:
   print("1st case: The ID stays the same")
else:
   print("1st case: The ID has changed")

# Check now what happens if you create a new list
my_list = [3, 2, 1]
new_id = id(my_list)
if original_id == new_id:
   print("2nd case: The ID stays the same")
else:
   print("2nd case: The ID has changed")
```

The obtained result is the following:

```
1st case: The ID stays the same
2nd case: The ID has changed
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you are interested in learning more about the topic, search about _mutable vs immutable_ objects in Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, your `num[2]=5` replaces values in first loop instance itself, so 5 is printed in the normal loop.

Your second code:

It's actually replacing and only `i` is printed in second code.

You need to print `num` to check the replaced value.

**Code:**

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in num:
    print(i)
    num = [5 if j==3 else j for j in num ]
    
print (num)# This line
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
[1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know why the "i" did not update as the previous one.

Comment: Explained in the answer also. It's actually mutated in the first instance of lopp itself. So 5 is printed in the 3rd loop instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop already gets an iterator of `num`, and while inside loop you modify `num`, then the `for` loop does not look again to `num`, and iterates using the old list.